# How to create JMS backed Channel using Java Config

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I know how to create a JMS backed channel using something like this

```
<int-jms:channel id="ticketChannel" queue-name="ticket.queue" connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

I want to know how to create the same using Spring Java Config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean
public JmsChannelFactoryBean ticketChannel() {
    JmsChannelFactoryBean fb = new JmsChannelFactoryBean(true);
    fb.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    fb.setDestinationName("ticket.queue");
    // other props as needed.
    return fb;
}
```